# CakePHP Cookie Not Being Set

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I'm using the following code to set, and then read a cookie in CakePHP.

```
public $components = array('Cookie');
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Cookie->name = 'saved_times';
    $this->Cookie->time = '1 year';
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'localhost';
    $this->Cookie->path = '/';
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = false;
    $this->Cookie->key = '+%)asG_~s*SAr&bSIq34$@11qe@s!@v!@*(XSL#$XOw!a232d#HKis~#^';
    $this->Cookie->secure = false;

}
public function save_position($time){
    if($this->Auth->user('id')){
        //save to the database
        return true;
    }else{
        //set browser cookie
        $this->Cookie->write('time', $time);
        echo "set", $this->Cookie->read('time');
    }
}

public function read(){
    echo $this->Cookie->read('time'), "test";
    print_r($this->Cookie->read('time'));
}
```

The problem is that when I set the cookie I see, "set" and the cookie value echoed out, but when I visit `/read/` I'm only seeing "test" and no cookie value.  Also I'm using a cookie viewer in chrome, but I only see the `CAKEPHP` cookie for my domain not `saved_times`.  I don't think the cookie is even being set, but I don't know why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out cookies arent set until the View is rendered.  I had no view for my `save_position` action, so an error page was showing, which didnt set the cookie.  Once I added a `save_position.ctp` file everything worked okay.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue.